# htaccess - check multiple cookies with multiple values

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cookies, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to restrict folder and file access based on browser cookies.

Files can only be accessed if these 3 conditions are met:

1. Wordpress user is logged in
2. `example_cookie` exists
3. `example_cookie` is `value1` or `value2` BUT NOT anything else e.g. `value3`, `value4`, etc

My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example_cookie [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example_cookie=value1;? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example_cookie=value2;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Just having the first 2 conditions seems to be working fine by themselves.

The last 2 conditions still blocks access if not logged in or if `example_cookie` is not set but allows access for any set value of `example_cookie` not just `value1` or `value2`.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (edited) posted code does work now. On line 4, I had the `;?` around the wrong way! I also didn't need line 3.
Final code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example_cookie=value1;? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !example_cookie=value2;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```